# Who can charge a ring of storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Ring of spell storing specifies that it requires attunement.  That's fine, that makes sense for *using* the ring.

But the text on charging it states that 'Any creature can cast a spell...'  Does the phrase 'any creature' bypass the attunement requirement?  Does it allow the party's wizard to charge the fighter's ring of spell storing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, rules in D&D5 mean exactly what they say; no more, no less.

The relevant parts of the description are (my emphasis):

> **RING OF SPELL STORING**
>
> *Ring, rare (requires attunement)*
>
> This ring stores spells cast into it, holding them until the
>   attuned wearer uses them. ...
>
> Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level
>   into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast. ...
>
> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored
>   in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell
>   attack bonus, and spellcasting ability **of the original
>   caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell**. ...

**Does the phrase 'any creature' bypass the attunement requirement?**

You have to be an "attuned wearer" to use them and it is
petty clear the "original caster" and "you" can be different people. So, you do not need to be attuned to cast a spell *into* the ring; only out of it.

**Does it allow the party's wizard to charge the fighter's ring of spell storing?**

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my reading, Dale M -- just wanted to double check it.